# Library that iterates multiple yields returning promises in a generator function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a node.js library or a decent script around that can:

- Iterate through multiple (not one!) yields in a Generator
- Wait for those yielded Promises to resolve
- Push yielded data back from the iterator into the generator?

Comment: i don't see how you can "push values into a resolved promise", so no.

Comment: You're aware of `co` of course?